# Creating a file browser

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, file, encryption, selector

I need a file selector in an iPhone application I am developing to select a file to encrypt? Any idea how I would go about accessing files on the iPhone?

It would be something like this: http://iphone.heinelt.eu/?Applications:iFile:File_Browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re making a file browser, you’re probably taking the wrong approach. The design philosophy of iOS—and the Human Interface Guidelines—strongly recommend that you not expose the filesystem unless you really, really have to. Generally, collections of documents in iOS apps are displayed as a flat list—witness the built-in Notes app as well as Apple’s own iWork (Pages / Keynote / Numbers) suite. You can display that list in a UITableView, which you can find plenty of documentation about and tutorials for by [Googling it](http://google.com/search?q=uitableview).